# How to control the speed of animation in Swift using curveEaseInOut or Keyframes?

Tags: ios, animation, swift3

Using Swift 3, I am animating several UILabels 'sliding' them from right to left.
The labels are of varying lengths.

I'm trying to get their speed to appear the same regardless of the length.

I'm using this code but which does not really give me the visual effect I need because I can only change the duration for each label based on length and nature of the curve doesn't really account for this:

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 5.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut,.repeat], animations: {
            self.Label_1.frame.origin.x = -self.Label_1.frame.width
        }, completion: nil)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, delay: 5.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut,.repeat], animations: {
            self.Label_2.frame.origin.x = -self.Label_2.frame.width
        }, completion: nil)
```

What happens is the animation speeds up until the midpoint then slows down. It appears to me that the curveEaseInOut motion curve does not account for a period of constant speed between the 'eases'. This terrible graphic I've drawn should help:

[image]

1) shows the apparent visual nature of the curve - where the ease-in and ease-out transition without any constant speed in between whereas
2) shows what I am trying to achieve.

With 2) I could specify the length in time of the ease-in, the ease-out, and the constant speed between.

How can I achieve the effect I'm after?

Comment: I think you need to use KeyFramed animation to do this

Comment: @ReinierMelian - thanks I'll try key frames

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple, but easy to achieve animation. What you really want to do is to create a layer for this animation. Something like this, it won't work for what you are doing because it has different variables, but it worked for me.

```
  let labelSpringAnimationIn = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
    labelSpringAnimationIn.fromValue = -100.0
    labelSpringAnimationIn.toValue = 200.0
    labelSpringAnimationIn.duration = 2.0

    //this duration can be whatever you want, if you want the cons
    //you can find what these mean by searching in the documentation
    labelSpringAnimationIn.initialVelocity = 3.0
    labelSpringAnimationIn.damping = 9.8

    let labelSpringAnimationOut = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
    labelSpringAnimationOut.fromValue = 200.0
    labelSpringAnimationOut.toValue = -100.0
    labelSpringAnimationOut.duration = 2.0

    //this duration can be whatever you want, if you want the cons
    //you can find what these mean by searching in the documentation
    labelSpringAnimationOut.initialVelocity = 3.0
    labelSpringAnimationOut.damping = 9.8


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.label.layer.add(labelSpringAnimationIn, forKey: nil)
    }, completion: {
        _ in UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
            self.label.layer.add(labelSpringAnimationOut, forKey: nil)

        }, completion: {
            _ in
            self.label.layer.removeAllAnimations()
            sleep(UInt32(3.0))
            self.labelAnimation()


        })
    })
```